# PANDAS new column using regular expression map to match on a dict with list values

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Imagine you have a list of dicts, each dict with its value as a list of values. Like so.

```
foods = [ 
    {'apples' : ['sweet', 'round', 'red'] }, 
    {'liver' : ['juicy', 'flat', 'nasty'] }, 
    {'chocolate': ['tasty', 'block', 'dark' ] } 
]
```

Now imagine a simple dataframe with a column of names, like so:

```
menu = [
    {'Name' : ['Sweet caramel bananas', 'Juicy farm salad', 'Hog face dark ice-cream destruction'] }
    {'Price' : [20, 15, 32] }
]
yum_yums = pandas.DataFrame(menu)
```

Let's say you want to create a category of food for each menu item. For example, since sweet caramel bananas contain apples, it should have the 'apple' key as a category.

What's the best way to go about using a regular expression to match the values in the dicts in that first list to values in the NAME column, creating a new column with the key as the assigned category?

The end result would look like:

```
menu = [
    {'Name' : ['Sweet caramel bananas', 'Juicy farm salad', 'Hog face dark ice-cream destruction'] }
    {'Price' : [20, 10, 32] }
    {'Category' : ['apple', 'liver', 'chocolate'] }
]
food_w_cat = pandas.DataFrame(menu)
```

Comment: I don't see what you want to use regex for. I don't really see what the problem is at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a regular expression, you can simply loop through both the menu and the categories such as:

```
category = []
#iterate through menu names
for i_name in menu[0]['Name']:

    #transform menu name to lowercase for comparison
    i_name_lower = [i.lower() for i in i_name.split(' ')]

    #enable multiple categories of food per menu
    food_category = []

    #iterate through food categories
    for i_foods in foods:       

        key = list(i_foods.keys())[0]   

        if any([j in i_name_lower for j in i_foods[key]]):
            food_category.append(key)

    category.append(food_category)

menu.append({'category':category})
```

Output then is such as:

```
[{'Name': ['Sweet caramel bananas',
   'Juicy farm salad',
   'Hog face dark ice-cream destruction']},
 {'Price': [20, 15, 32]},
 {'category': [['apples'], ['liver'], ['chocolate']]}]
```